# Button not responding to HTML-table export to Excel - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to export a html-table to excel.
When I'm using this code the table tries to export as soon the table is loaded:

```
<script>

    $("#excel").table2excel({
        exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
        name: "Kontrakt",
        filename: "Kontrakt.xls"
    });
</script>
```

But when I try to use a btn to execute the export it does not respond:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnExport").click(function () {
          $("#excel").table2excel({
            exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
            name: "Kontrakt",
            filename: "Kontrakt.xls"
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need help solving this.

EDIT: More code

```
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value="Export" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/table2excel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Try put something like alert() or console.log() in the click() event and see does it trigger? Or post the relevent html code.

Comment: An alert works. But the export does not.

Comment: Any error(s) in the browser console?

Comment: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'table2excel'.
But it works without the button

Comment: Browser is blocking download `a` tag for some reason... Without any message. Does in work in Internet Explorer? (it has another save method)

Comment: Does not work in any browser with the button.

Comment: Please convert you code to a Code snippet here, or use jsfiddle. But please use not minified library for table2excel, because in minified version the error is inside variable setters.

Comment: "<a class='gotoLine' href='#175:17'>175:17</a> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).table2excel is not a function"

Comment: Last comment was from jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a input type checkbox in the form and then querying if the checkbox was set.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ruta" /></td>

@if (ruta == "on")
{
   <script>
      $("#excel").table2excel({
      exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
      name: "Kontrakt",
      filename: "Kontrakt.xls"
      });
    </script>
}
```